# how to upgrade CentOS 5.11 to 6.x

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, redhat, rhel

I have tried executing yum update command but it only took me from 5.11 to 6.x.  I need the server to be running CentOS 6.x for nagiosxi.

```
[root@nagiosxi network-scripts]# uname -a
Linux nagiosxi.inl.gov 2.6.18-371.8.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Apr 24 18:23:07 EDT 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you looked at the CentOS/RedHat documentation?

Comment: Yes i have, it wasn't really clear as to how to do it

Comment: Which documentation specifically? It likely wasn't clear because that's generally not how they recommend doing things. Though there are (and have been) semi-official ways of doing it since CentOS 6 I believe.

Comment: Because you are upgrading to a major version, the safest way is to run preupgrade. Here's what centos has to offer http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool

Answer (score 3):

As you probably know, CentOS is based on RedHat so the same rules apply for both.

In place upgrades between 4, 5, and 6 are not supported by RedHat (and thus CentOS).  The only supported upgrade path is from 6 to 7. The expectation is that an upgrade path will continue in future releases.

With that said, there is a way to upgrade from 5 to 6 but it is not supported by RedHat so be careful with how you use it.

The link is: [In place upgrade](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/21964)